# How to implement a program which runs about 12 hours on a server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a program which analyses market data. The program will fetch stocks' price from Yahoo Finance every five minutes and stores the data to database.  I would like to know if it is reasonable to call Thread.sleep(5mins) in Java to pause the program every five minutes? Or is that any other better solution to do that?
Moreover, I also want to know if the program can be integrated to MVC frameworks, such as Java Spring (http://spring.io/).  I only know a bit about Java Spring MVC and it is great for Websites or cloud applications.  But, for a program which continuously runs, is it possible to be integrated to Java Spring.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You may want to see this [page](http://www.javamexico.org/blogs/jpaul/ejemplo_basico_quartz_221_tomcat_7054_con_edicion_de_expresion_cron) (it's a example with Quartz).

Comment: If you're starting with an app, i strongly recommend that you use Java EE 7, then you can use the @Schedule

Comment: @rekiem87, thanks, I have learnt some basic Java SE, and hopefully Java EE would not be too difficult to pick up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest to use such low level threading.

This sounds like exact match for some batching framework. I would Suggest to take a look at [Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/index.html) or [Java EE 7 batching](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/batch_applications_in_java_ee).

If you are planning to maintain and extend such batch application, initial learning curve will be payed back 10 times.

Comment: there's even a getting started guide for spring batch: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Comment: Thank you so much.  I did not know that there is a Spring Batch in Spring MVC. Thanks.

Comment: @ColemanTung Spring Batch and Spring MVC are separate projects. But both are very easy to integrate in one application.